Access Forbidden Error 403 with Apache on XAMPP (Linux, Fedora): Can't Access Alias Directory
I’m trying to set up a project on XAMPP (Linux, Fedora) and access it through an alias in Apache. My project is located outside the default /opt/lampp/htdocs/ directory, so I created an alias in my Apache configuration. The alias points to /home/username/2024/l3-DevWeb/php/test.
However, when I try to access my project via http://localhost:8080/mon-projet, I get a 403 Forbidden error:
Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
Apache is running on port 8080, and MySQL is also running without any issues. I have verified the permissions of the project folder and its files, and I’ve configured Apache to grant access, but the error persists.

Configured an Alias in Apache's httpd.conf:

Alias /mon-projet "/home/username/2024/l3-DevWeb/php/test"

<Directory "/home/username/2024/l3-DevWeb/php/test">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>



Changed the permissions on the project directory:

sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/username/project/path/test
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/username/project/path/test


Restarted Apache through XAMPP:

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart


Keep in mind that the http server process needs r and x permissions not only on the folder itself, but on all folders leading up to it from the file system root.
